# Find one DOM node when several share the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at one place in jquery, In have multiple dropdowns which is generating dynamically and have the same class name.
I am trying to trigger a click event on that class but that is affecting all of them.
What i want is just to point to the one which comes in a loop not to all

Something like this. ?

here is the jquery

```
if(olddate[0]==='')
{
   $(".month").first().val($(".month option:first").first().trigger("change"));
}
if(olddate[1]==='')
{
   $(".day").val($(".day option:first").trigger("change"));
}
if(olddate[2]==='')
{
   $(".year").val($(".year option:first").trigger("change"));
}
```

Comment: Code needs more context. Where is the loop?

Comment: show us html code also.

Comment: 1. you can't have _multiple class[es] with the same name_, but rather multiple elements with the same class; 2. use IDs then.

Comment: @moonwave99 Dont guide incorrectly. You can have classes with same name but not ids.

Comment: Sounds a bit like your event handler is editting all elements with that className, instead of only the event.target. Make sure your handler has a way to check which element was clicked.

Comment: @moonwave99 You are confusing.

Comment: @epascarello Hi here is the link of http://trendzinfotech.com/date/index.php 
I am using combodate.js 
the issue is the first date is 02/02/2015 and the second one is /03/2015
Now as on second date i dont have a month i am just making a click on month at empty element , but you can see its making month empty on first date too

Comment: @Akki619 : Please check the above comment

Comment: @moonwave99 : you can use as many class with the same name i know that

Comment: @RohitArora An HTML element can **have** one or more classes, and multiple elements may share the same class[es] of course. But a class is just a string, so _having classes with same name_ makes no sense in this context. Mine was just a remark about logic, not about HTML specs.

Comment: @moonwave99 please read your previous comment again. That doesn't tell anyone that you were remarking about logic. Everyone in this thread took it in wrong way. Not only me.

Comment: @RohitArora ...besides the one who edited the title and answered the question : )) Classes may not _share names_, because they are names themselves! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code work, you have to create "context" somehow. Context can be:

- Wrap each dropdowns in an element has an ID. You can then do `$('#id .month')` to locate the node. See [Descendant Selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
- Save the root of the dropdown in a JavaScript variable. You can then do `$('.class', rootNode)` to locate it. See [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Aaron Digulla :)